# Service: typeof is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am getting error:
tried using like: "useClass: ApidataService" or "ApidataService" in providers and also remove public from the service constructor.

Failed to compile.

```
C:/wamp64/www/angular/project/src/app/app.module.ts (33,69): Argument of type '{ declarations: (typeof AppComponent | typeof ViewComponent | typeof AboutComponent | typeof News...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'.
  Types of property 'providers' are incompatible.
    Type '{ provide: InjectionToken<string>; useValue: string; ApidataService: typeof ApidataService; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'.
      Type '{ provide: InjectionToken<string>; useValue: string; ApidataService: typeof ApidataService; }' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
        Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ApidataService' does not exist in type 'Provider'.
```

My service is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ApidataService {

  public  constructor() { }
    cars = ['cars','bycycle','van'];
    mydata(){
        return "this is from apidata";
    }
}
```

And app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ViewComponent } from './view/view.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { NewsComponent } from './news/news.component';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';   //for 2way binding

//SERVICES SAMPLE
import {ApidataService} from './apidata.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ViewComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    NewsComponent    
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {path:'About',component:AboutComponent},
        {path:'News',component:NewsComponent}
    ])
  ],
    providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: 'http://localhost:4200/',ApidataService}
     ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `useClass` to add class to provider

```
providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: 'http://localhost:4200/', useClass: ApidataService}
 ],
```

Comment: getting error :Unhandled Promise rejection: url.replace is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: url.replace is not a function
    at _stripIndexHtml (common.es5.js:417)

Answer (score 0):

The ApidataService has to be added as the second item in the providers list like this:

```
providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: 'http://localhost:4200/' },
        { provide: ApidataService, useClass: ApidataService }
     ],
```

or shorter:

```
providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: 'http://localhost:4200/' },
        ApidataService
     ],
```